# Division of values as fraction output javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Example:

```
var x = 1/2
var y = 2/1

z=x/y ( 1/2 Divded 2/1) = 1/4 (Answer)
```

can this be achieved in javascript, id dont need decimal answers, i want output as 1/4

Comment: [yes it can be done, but it's not straightforward unless you use a library](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

Comment: Any suggestions on the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, with a [library](https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js), it's a quite easy task:

```
var x = new Fraction(1, 2);
var y = new Fraction(2, 1);

var z = x.div(y); // ( 1/2 Divded 2/1)

console.log(z.toFraction()); // 1/4 (Answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your math in such a way that it uses rational numbers instead of floating point values all the time. You might want to use a library for this, although I can't name one just now. But searching for arbitrary size rational numbers should yield usable results.

Or you do the computation using floating point math, then find an approximation of the result by a rational number. The way to do this is via [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations). Choosing an approximation here is a bit of a compromise: the more numeric error you allow, the smaller numerator and denominator will become, but the higher the chances that this resulting rational representation is different from what an all-rational computation would yield.

Answer (score 0):

```
function run( x, y )
{
    var z;

    z = x/y;

    //return '('+fracFormat( x )+')/('+fracFormat( y )+') -> '+fracFormat(z);
    //return '('+z+') -> '+fracFormat(z);
    return fracFormat(z);
}

function fracFormat( v )
{   
    var x,y,z;

    if( v === parseInt( v ) )
    {
        return ''+v;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 1/v;
        y = parseInt( x );

        if( x === y )
        {
            return '1/'+x;
        }
        else
        {
            z = (''+x).split('.')[1];
            x = parseInt( y+''+z );
            v = parseInt( '1'+zeros( z.length ) );
            y = gcf( v,  x );

            v = v/y;
            x = x/y;

            return v+'/'+x;
        }
    }
}

function zeros( total )
{
    var i, result = '';

    for( i=0; i<total; i++ )
    {
        result += '0';
    }

    return result;
}

function gcf( a, b )
{
    if( b == 0 )
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return gcf( b, a % b );
    }
}

var x = 1.5/2.75
,   y = 2.25/1.1
;
console.clear();
console.log( run( x, y ) );// output = 4/15
```